# Google apps, add-in, "You do not have permission to call getUserProperties"

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I find what permission do I need to set in the Oauth scopes to be able to use the getUserProperties in the google apps code inside a Google Docs add-in script code?

Comment: There is no scope needed for PropertiesService.  That error is not caused by the omission of a scope.  Is the user logged into multiple accounts or inside of a paid Google account/domain?

Comment: Can you post any repro steps? It works for me...

Comment: Google wrote to me that the permission should be added automatically when using getUserProperties in the script, and we changed nothing and suddenly it works, so it seems like it takes some time for Google to add this permission automatically when creating a new GCP project? Maybe some google cache issue?

Comment: This error happened to me as well. It's been around 10 hours now and it still throws this error. Not ideal as the users cannot use the Google Workplace Add-on.